# Find the number of different arrangements of the eleven letters in the word "PERSONALITY" if the arrangements are such that S, O and N are separated

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Find the number of different arrangements of the eleven letters in the word "PERSONALITY" if the arrangements are such that S, O and N are separated.

My Solution:

1. Find total number of ways to arrange 11 letters.
2. Find number of ways by having S,O and N together.
3. Use 1 - 2.

$11! - (9 \cdot 8! \cdot 3!)= 37 739 520$

But correct answer is $8! \cdot 9C3 \cdot 3! = 20 321 280$.

May I know what have I done wrong?

Comment: The book's answer would seem to require $S$ be separate from $O$, that $S$ also be separate from $N$ and that $O$ be separate from $N$... in other words, only words like SxxxOxxNxxx or xxNxOxSxxxx and such be counted.  Your approach seems to additionally count words like xxSOxxxxNxx where $S$ and $O$ were next to each other but $N$ was not which the book's answer deems as an invalid arrangement that should not have been counted.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose what the problem means by "S, O and N are separated" is that no two of them are adjacent. You've only subtracted out the ones that have these three letters collectively forming a single block. You've yet to exclude the ones with S-O adjacent, S-N adjacent and O-N adjacent.

The answer $8! \cdot 9C3 \cdot 3!$ suggests that such an arrangement that satisfies the requirements can be achieved by first arranging the 8 letters other than S, O and N (there are 8! ways to do so). Then, there are 9 places (the leftmost and rightmost positions, plus 7 gaps in between the 8 letters) among which you choose 3 to place S, O and N. Note that you can only place one of S, O and N in one gap, otherwise you will have two of them adjacent and violating the requirements. After choosing the 3 positions, you can then arrange S, O and N in $3!$ ways. The result then follows by the multiplication principle.